# I need to acces to the next page with selenium or Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I think I have already tried all the .click() .submit... all different kind of things but it doesn't do anything

What appears when I try to acces to the next page is the following, as as isn't a button or appears a web site I don't know what to do; the only thing that changes in all the pages is the number in the value, that here appears a 3

```
<ul class="pagination">
     <li><span onclick="document.lisarq.pagina.value=3; document.lisarq.submit(); " onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" style="cursor: pointer;">3</span></li>
</ul>
```

The only thing that I want to do is access to the next page in this case would be the 4 
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the link to the site you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I'm confused.  You say the next page is 4, but that html has `pagina.value=3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, to `click()` and access *Page 4* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination>li>span[onclick*='4']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pagination']/li/span[contains(@onclick, '4') and text()='4']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```